# What happens to 32-bit apps on a device after an iOS 11 update?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

I have several dozen 32-bit apps on my iPhone.  What happens to them after I update the device to iOS 11?

Is there any way to save these 32-bit apps off of the device? (for use with a spare iPhone 5, for instance)

Answer (score 6):

The data and application are both left intact. If you try to tap on those apps, it takes you to the settings / App Store to contact the developer and explaining the app will not run.

You can pre check on iOS 10 in the settings app.

- General > About > Applications

[image: Example 32 bit app warning]

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of the question, yes, if you have a version of iTunes prior to 12.7 which no longer syncs apps locally.

The files are stored in a subfolder of your iTunes folder and you should be able to transfer them to another phone as long as it uses the same AppleID as on the phone that it was downloaded for.